# What is the result of casting in C++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I've faced the next situation:

`char *arr[] = {"hello", (char *) 0};`

The above will create an array of char pointers and `arr[0]` will be pointing to the first character of "hello" string. But, what `(char *) 0` in this case is and where it could be used?

When I try to call `arr[1]` it gives me the next error:

> `segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Edit: i use it while creating the argv argument of posix_spawn function (it needs to have a null pointer on the last position):

> `The argument argv is an array of character pointers to null-terminated strings. The last member of this array shall be a null pointer and is not counted in argc.`

Comment: It's not really clear what you want and why you want to add the (char*)0 in your array.. you should describe your use case in more detail

Comment: The result of `(char *) 0)` is a null-pointer of type `char *`. Do you understand null-pointers?

Comment: The cast is actually redundant, `char *arr[] = {"hello", 0};` means exactly the same thing

Comment: You did not define argv[0]. Explain what you mean with "call argv[1]"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, `0` is a *null pointer constant*. It can be converted, with or without a cast, to any pointer type, giving a null pointer of that type. In modern C++, you can write `nullptr` to make it more clear that you mean a null pointer, not the number zero. There's also a `NULL` macro for the same purpose.

So here you have two pointers: one points to the string literal's array of characters, the other is null, and doesn't point to anything.

Dereferencing a null pointer gives undefined behaviour; typically, a segmentation fault, as you encountered.

Note that, in modern C++, you'll need `const char *` in order to point to the constant string literal `"hello"`. Older versions of the language allowed the dangerous conversion to a non-const `char *` for compatibility with ancient C code that didn't have a concept of `const`; that nastiness has now finally been removed from the language.

Answer (score 2):

arr[1] is a null pointer, a pointer with the value 0. You use it in situation where your pointer does not point to a valid object. For example the next pointer of the last node in a linked list. Accessing a null pointer leads to undefined behaviour and often segmentation faults.